# Difference LowPass Filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

These circuits have lowpass circuit. One of these has passive lowpass filter. Another one is active lowpass filter. Both circuits filtered signal for opamp input. Why we have two diiferent circuits? What is these circuits differences? Please explain detailed..

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate both? What differences could you find?

Comment: Actually I have not simulated these circuit. Just I wonder. These circuit are lowpass filter examples. Why we need two different topologies? What is the differences?

Comment: Or are these circuits same for filter designs. If circuits are different, which parameters effect?

Comment: without any feedback resistor for the op-amp circuit U1 on the left, you will have infinite gain and the output will saturate to 0V, as you have tied the (+) of the input to Gnd.
note: this would only be an issue if you simulate the circuits and are comparing the nets OUTx.

Comment: The two circuits are not at all compatible. To make them compatible you need an input resistor for the op-amp on the right and you need to totally rethink what you drew on the left.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My fault. I edited my question immediately. If circuit on the right has a  input resistor, what is the difference these two circuits for filter design?

Comment: @Andyaka please look at again

Comment: @bb0667 I suggest re-drawing U1 with the RC connected to the (+) terminal, and the (-) connected to OUT1. this will configure U1 in a non-inverting unity follower

Comment: Start by simulating them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all (as [@nohu42](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/346305/nohu42) and [@Electrocol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/313751/electrocol) explained) you need to use a [buffer circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier#Op-amp_implementation) which is not the one you showed.

Now, let's assume that you used the correct buffer circuit. Let's call the left circuit, circuit \$1\$, and the other one circuit \$2\$. The transfer functions of the circuits are given by:

$$\mathscr{H}_1\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space1}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space1}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}}=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle1+\text{sCR}}\tag1$$
$$\mathscr{H}_2\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{o}\space\text{|}\space2}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_{\text{i}\space\text{|}\space2}\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\space\text{||}\space\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}=-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\cdot\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{R}_2}=-\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle1+\text{sCR}_2}\tag2$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

So, we can see that:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}_1\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)^2}}\tag3$$
$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{1+\left(\omega\text{CR}_2\right)^2}}\tag4$$

So, they act (in theory at least) the same when \$\displaystyle\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2\$.

---

Just for completeness, let's also find the argument:

$$\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}_1\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}\right)\tag5$$
$$\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}_2\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\pi-\arctan\left(\omega\text{CR}_2\right)\tag6$$

Meaning that for circuit \$2\$ you have a phase shift of \$\pi\$ radian between output and input.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit on the left is not correct to me. With no feedback path the gain will be infinite as pointed out by @Electrocol.

Also, I guess the circuit on the left should be a non inverter lowpass filter. If I'm correct the input must be in the positive entry of the OPAMP circuit. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4svfO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The most obvious difference between those two circuit (assuming tehe correction for the left circuit) is simply the sign of the static gain. On the left, the static gain is positive, on the right the static gain is negative. Meaning that on the right you have a phase shift of pi radian between output and input